# AngularJS details directive doesn't work on firefox

Tags: angularjs, firefox, directive, html-tag-details

I am using the angularJS 1.3, and found that the  directive doesn't work on firefox 29. Even the test page on the angular site doesn't show the arrow,

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOpen

Any clue on this? Or I have customize to or order to work on FF?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like a bug related to FF. Take care, you are using an UNSTABLE version of Angular JS. The most recent version is v1.2.16

Comment: I just tested on 1.2.16, and the problem persists.

Comment: I opened a ticket for this bug. This is related to FF and IE, that doesn't implement the feature necessary to run this directive. You can see the issue here at the AngulaJS github: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/7337

Answer (score 0):

Really, it doesn't work.

But, if you need, you can use something like:

```
<details id="details" ng-show="open">
    <summary>Show/Hide me</summary>
</details>
```

using **ng-show** in replacement to ng-open

Comment: Well, I try on chrome to understand the problem... and, only the ng-show doesn't will substitute the original comportment.

Comment: And, also on chrome, there are problems... when is used the check to open/close, it works correctly... but, when you click directly on component, the correspondent check doesn't will be checked.